# How to convert SQLCMD scripts to vanilla Transact-SQL DDL/DML?

Tags: .net, sql-server, visual-studio-2012, sqlcmd

I am using **SQLServer Data Tools** (SSDT) in Visual Studio 2012 to synchronise my database versions. The SSDT compare feature functions by preparing an SQLCMD compatible script which is executed against the database that must be updated.

I would like to know if there is an automated way to prepare vanilla **T-SQL DML/DDL** update scripts as an alternative to the SQLCMD. A viable alternatively that would work, is to convert the SQLCMD script to the raw script. Is there a tool available that can do this?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't run SQLCMD? I don't know of any tools to do this - just wondering why SQLCMD won't work. You can set that in SSMS if that's the issue. I added a button to my toolbar for when I need to run scripts manually.

Comment: Yes there is a valid reason. I don't have control of the database server and I am limited to providing a DDL script via a third part application.

Comment: Is there a reason that the release team can't use either SQLPackage with a bundled dacpac file or use SQLCMD to push the scripts? (other than not wanting to change, that is...) We do most of our releases straight out of the project or out of the dacpac we build from source. Not aware of any tools to convert to straight TSQL, but running in SQLCMD mode works with little trouble. It even makes it easier for the release team to run in an automated fashion.